# Selenium error - ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was using the selenium module but all of a sudden I get this error

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

here is my simple code that gives me the error

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
```

Comment: I try your code, and it works...

Comment: weird. could there be something i did to my computer that u may know of that could cause this problem? i cant seem to stop it from getting that error

Comment: I got this error when using the chromedriver and I downloaded the latest version of chromedriver and it was fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the new firefox 47 update was the problem and I had to downgrade it to firefox 46

i got the infor from here
[Selenium Webdriver halting with [Errno 10054]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445406/selenium-webdriver-halting-with-errno-10054)

Comment: You should accept your own answer if you found the solution to your problem!

Answer (score 1):

May be is time to upgrade Webdriver for your navigator. I had the same problem using Chrome, and it was solved replacing the existing chromedriver.exe (windows in my case) with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post as I had the same problem. Updating to newest version of geckodriver fixed the problem for me